# Se puede contar un sum en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una duda , necesito CONSULTAR la cantidad (total) de clientes con ventas superiores a $30.000.000 en una base de datos, he logrado seleccionar solamente los clientes que tengan ventas mayores a la cantidad mencionada anteriormente, pero como hago para consultar la cantidad de clientes que cumplan esta condición? ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer algo como Count(sum()) en una consulta?

Solo he logrado hacer esto hasta ahora:

```sql
SELECT   c.Nombre,
         SUM(v.VALOR_VENTA * v.CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO) amount
FROM     Cliente c 
         INNER JOIN Ventas v ON v.ID_CLIENTE = c.Id
GROUP BY c.Nombre
HAVING   SUM(v.VALOR_VENTA * v.CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO) > 30000000
```

Comment: si.. usa un count sobre esta consulta y listo ;) usa esta consulta de subconsulta...

Comment: Pon tu codigo como texto, no como imagen

Answer (score 2):

En Sql Server podrias usar un CTE (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Explora las CTE ya que además de funcionar como como `tablas derivadas` ofrece otras prestaciones como actualizar o eliminar filas cuando se usa con `UPDATE` o `DELETE`

```
;with
 c1 as (select c.ID,c.Nombre, sum(v.valor_venta * v.cantidad_producto) as amount
          from Clientes as c
               inner join Ventas as v
               on v.id_cliente = c.id
          group by c.ID,c.Nombre
          having sum(v.valor_venta * v.cantidad_producto) > 30000000)
select count(1)
  from c1
```

O en otros motores de bases de datos puedes utiliza una `tabla derivada` (a veces llamada también `subconsulta`) que, para entenderlo de una manera sencilla, es darle un alias a un conjunto de resultados. En este caso al conjunto de resultados que sumariza la columna `amount` se le da el alias `c1` (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6038/sql-server-derived-table-example/)

```
select count(1)
  from (select c.ID,c.Nombre, sum(v.valor_venta * v.cantidad_producto) as amount
          from Clientes as c
               inner join Ventas as v
               on v.id_cliente = c.id
          group by c.ID,c.Nombre
          having sum(v.valor_venta * v.cantidad_producto) > 30000000) as c1
```